# Fonts have changed in Dia on Windows, my diagrams are broken

Tags: windows, dia

Suddenly the fonts in all my diagrams have fonts, ruining the layout of some of them.  I tried deleting Dia's configuration, but it didn't help.

The only thing I can think of that might have caused it is installing LibreOffice yesterday.  How does Dia decide which fonts to use and where does it get them from?  I haven't changed any font settings in Dia, and my diagrams all use default fonts.

I'm using Dia 0.97.2.

Answer (score 0):

Dia uses the standard fonts that the operating system provides.

- Did you check your diagrams on a second system?
- Have you tried to uninstall the software that triggered your problem?
- Could you give an example of a font that you're using?

Comment: I'm using the default fonts, but I can't find a setting where I can see what those are. Some of the objects have a font setting, the selected font there is "sans". So I guess the problem is that which font "sans" is can change depending on which fonts you have installed on the system.

Comment: I could change the font to just Arial or something, but not all of the UML objects have got a font setting at all. So I'm stuck with the defaults if I want to avoid using several different fonts in the same chart. So maybe the best solution is to just export a diagram as SVG when it's done, and not rely on the original file being usable.

Comment: Dia 0.98 will provide more comprehensive control over UML object fonts.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to it.